# Why L1 Regularization does not work with Calculus Training methods?

Tags: neural-networks, modeling, regularization, train

I quite understand What is **L1** and **L2** regularization, but the authors of articles keep saying that:

> To summarize, **L1** regularization sometimes has a nice side effect of pruning out unneeded features by setting their associated weights to 0.0 but **L1** regularization doesn’t easily work with all forms of training. [1]

Can someone point me the directions to understand why is that?

Thanks!

[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/dn904675.aspx)
[2](http://www.chioka.in/differences-between-l1-and-l2-as-loss-function-and-regularization/)

Comment: By "calculus training methods" do you simply mean methods that make use of derivative information?

Comment: By calculus I meant models that uses calculus to train. @Glen_b

Comment: Do you mean anything *other* than "makes use of derivative information"?

Comment: @Glen_b  to be honest I just repeated what the authors ever say about this regularization. I just found out that derivative is the "why" behind all this. Fell free to edit

Comment: Can you offer a full reference (authors, title etc) to what you're quoting?

Comment: @Glen_b just updated the quesstion

Comment: It's good to include links but it's still not clear in your question who you're quoting. Please state author, title and so on in your question for the text that you have quoted.

Comment: I just read those links, btw why you need this?

Comment: Its a site-requirement. Some guidelines are here - [help: How to reference material written by others](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Is there no way to tell who wrote the text you posted in your question? (Usual convention on cross-validated would generally include more information than that described at the help, typically close to a full reference)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that L1 regularization requires absolute values of parameters, and the absolute value function is not differentiable at zero. So the usual gradient-based methods (including second-order methods) are not applicable.

Non-differentiable functions have to be handled in some other way. In particular, L1 regularization can be framed as a quadratic programming problem, if I recall correctly.